# Google map v2 issue in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello friends i want to display map in my android device so my  code is as below

**main.xml**

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    />
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pakagename.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- android:versionCode="2" -->
<!-- android:versionName="1.1" > -->

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
     android:required="true"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.pakagename.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.pakagename.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name=".RestaurantApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_API_KEY"
       />
    <activity
        android:name="pkg.android.rootways.restaurantapp.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="pkg.android.rootways.restaurantapp.ReviewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />


    </application>

 </manifest>
```

**ReviewActivity.java**

```
 public class ReviewActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
 {
           @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GoogleMap myMap;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.res_review);

    initMap();
         }

public void initMap() {

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

    if (myMap != null)
    {
        System.out.println("MAp");
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);         
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Null Value");
    }

   }

   }
```

when i run ablove code it gave me error like

```
   12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420): Caused by:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does   not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following   declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    12-02 16:23:55.544: E/AndroidRuntime(25420):
```

any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 3):

**I solve isssus**

Issue in map api key i create first api key but it is not runnig then i create second api key for the same pakagename so there r two api key for same pakage thaerefore it may conflict the key so i make solution like i create new api key with new pakage name and it is working for me

Comment: this is perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your manifest file :

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Also check this : [Google Maps V2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Siddarth Vyas:: As per your suggestion i add one more meta-data tag in my manifest file it reduce error but now other error comes my mapview not show it gave message like ** The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.**

Comment: Have you added google-play services lib as per the link that I have provided??

Comment: @Siddarth Vyas ::Yes Siddharth i follow all steps which above link included but still not dispaly map

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya : Then please again check your Map Api V2 Key.

Comment: @Siddarth Vyas: i solve issue just see my answer and thanks for your time and effort brother!!