# The Map Doesn't Show, only show Grid, and Show Grey Background

Tags: android, google-maps

i just want to ask i want to make googlemaps apps on android..
i have follow instruction from many website (include from google developer) but the apps doesn't work on my real device (on Android 4.2.2) can anyone help me? Please..
The Code Look Like This.

xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The AndroidManifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wilis.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >    
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.wilis.googlemaps.GoogleMaps"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAOGow0GmvoOi87cCFQffmRVz4SNmEWnP0"/>

</application>    
</manifest>
```

And The Main Activity file :

```
package com.wilis.googlemaps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class GoogleMaps extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :

[Google Maps V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278325/java-lang-nullpointerexception-googlemaps-v2/20278406#20278406) , [Google Maps V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326641/google-map-v2-issue-in-android/20326706#20326706) and [Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only gray backgrounds shows in case of incorrect API_KEY. Probably you mixed up debug and production keys.

Comment: i think so, but, how to get a right API_KEY? i already have SHA1 fingerprint A8:C5:CD:20:1B:F9:C9:DF:7F:A8:15:B2:52:7B:04:69:EE:CD:4B:3F;com.example.googlemap, and i put this code into google api console, but it still not working..

Comment: @ndr_sd where your debug keystore is located?

Comment: in the C:\Users\Andrew\.android\debug keystore

Answer (score 0):

Use MapView in your xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyCpC852JtX3dHjqGP6UnJBygJUdO0w_pBY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/mMapView"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

and Use the below code for the GoogleActivity:

```
public class GoogleActivity extends Activity {
    private GoogleMap mGglMpInstance;
    private MapView mMapView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(MainActivity.this);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            initailizeLayout(savedInstanceState);
        }

        private void initailizeLayout(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            mMapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mMapView);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mGglMpInstance=mMapView.getMap();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and **make sure that generate api key with package name which is mentioned in android manifest file and your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.**

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.

And make sure following steps done correct or not:

Steps:
* to ensure that device has Google Play services APK
* to install Google Play Service rev. more than 2

[image]

- to create project at https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- to enable "Google Maps Android API v2"
  [image]
- to register of SHA1 in project (**NOW, YOU NEED WRITE SHA1;your.app.package.name**) at APIs console and get API KEY
- to copy directory ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib to root of your project
- to add next line to the YOUR_PROJECT/project.properties

`android.library.reference.1=google-play-services_lib`

- to add next lines to the YOUR_PROJECT/proguard-project.txt

`-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {`

`protected Object[][] getContents();`

`}`

Okay, now you ready to create your own Google Map app with using Google Map APIs V2 for Android.

If you create application with min SDK = 8, please use android support library v4 + SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

Answer (score 0):

try to enable **Googlre map api v2** in **services** of  **google api console**

you have copy pasted the api key try to create a api key your own ...

[how to create a Google API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: have you add the Google play library as a reference to your project and place that library in the same working directory ,copy the google play library from android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

Comment: you have copy pasted the api key, it wrong,you have to create your own key ,i have even provided the how to create an api key above 'how to create a Google API key'...

Comment: but i already have create an api key in the google apis console, it look like this A8:C5:CD:20:1B:F9:C9:DF:7F:A8:15:B2:52:7B:04:69:EE:CD:4B:3F;com.example.googlema‌​p

Comment: by go to create an API key click on that you an see you have an project after that then you can see create android key after then copy pasted the sha-1;package name and even enable services ogf google map api android v2 and  then you have created an API key ,coppy that api key paste it in the <meta tag  api key="">

Comment: you package name which you are taking is wrong A8:C5:CD:20:1B:F9:C9:DF:7F:A8:15:B2:52:7B:04:69:EE:CD:4B:3F;com.example.googlema‌​‌​p

Comment: add your package name as show below in the eclipse, by going to preferences-->android-->build-->sha-1 key fingerprint copy that and add your package i can you your package name is "com.wilis.googlemaps",but you package before which you have add is different add this...