# Google Map for Android - authentication issue

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This is my `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My API Key" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And this is `ActivityMain.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /* onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected omitted */
}
```

And finally, Always I am getting following error message

```
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I have searched lot in google, But I can't find solution.

Note: I have enabled `Google Maps Android API v2` in [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~hip-principle-637/apiui/api)

Any solution will be highly appreciable,

Comment: where is ur map code implementation in class

Comment: @KSSS I have follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) tutorial. There is no map code implementation. Can you tell me what have to do.

Comment: Have you turned on Android Google API v2 in API console?

Comment: @shylendra There is nothing like that..

Comment: GoogleMap googlemap;googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
      .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: @KSSS Already tried this friend

Comment: @Gunaseelan see here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key

Comment: @shylendra Can't get you, what are you trying to tell me friend.

Comment: k. Then go to api consone. click ur project=>APIS&AUTH=>API=>TURN ON Google Maps Android API v2

Comment: are you created API key with SHA-1 key + package name mentioned in the manifest file. i.e.,your SHA-1+com.example.googlemaps

Answer (score 0):

It should be issue with your API key, Once uninstall and re install it again so that you can simply clear application data

and also make sure this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

and use SupportMapFragment as:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

instead of MapFragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

ANd make sure Google Maps Android API v2 turned on:

1. Go to [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
2. Go to **services** section
3. Enable **Google Maps Android API v2**
4. Follow all the steps in the documentacion

For more info refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341707/the-map-doesnt-show-only-show-grid-and-show-grey-background/20343438#20343438)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sample.zsample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.sample.zsample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sample.zsample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sample.zsample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your api key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
 }
}
```