# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: onCreate in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i update ADT to latest version, i integrate Google maps in my project .

MapActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);

    // fetch the map view from the layout
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    // make available zoom controls
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    return false;

}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBOhdOOMI_ZMYlvSyi7DVeRe_bo9ckxehM"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

My question when i run this on my device it was giving me error

```
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror
```

after that i tried to fix it through  "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties" . now its giving me error

```
08-05 15:02:21.387: E/AndroidRuntime(20647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 15:02:21.387: E/AndroidRuntime(20647): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: onCreate
08-05 15:02:21.387: E/AndroidRuntime(20647):    at        com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(Native Method)
08-05 15:02:21.387: E/AndroidRuntime(20647):    at  com.example.careandcure.MapsViewActivity.onCreate(MapsViewActivity.java:12)
```

how to solve this..

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the old Maps v1 API. Consider upgrading to v2.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341707/the-map-doesnt-show-only-show-grid-and-show-grey-background/20343438#20343438

Comment: may b kindly can u give link for v2..

Answer (score 0):

instead of mapview use fragment -

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```